# Can't locate WebSphere web container HTTP TRANSPORT port in Admin Console

Tags: websphere

I am trying to determine the value of the standard HTTP TRANSPORT port in a WebSphere application server via the WAS Admin Console.  The WebSphere documentation says that it should be available here:

Servers > Application Servers > server_name > Web Container Settings > Web Container > HTTP Transports > host_name.

However, I don't see any reference at all to "HTTP Transports" on the "Web Container" page.

I also looked under here:

Servers > Application servers > cmsComm006c_tst > Ports

but none of the ports described there are related to the web container.

There are numerous web app modules running and accepting traffic in the application server, so the port must be configured somewhere, but I can't seem to find that info via the admin console.

FWIW, I only have read privileges in the admin console, if that might possibly be related.

Forgive me if this question has been asked and answered before, I did a good bit of googling before posting and did not see anything quite like this.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on one of the transport chains. Preferably the httpQueueInboundDefault. I think that this is the port you are looking for.

You should be able to reach the same info by going through server_name > Ports  and click on the 'view associated transport' link of the WC_defaulthost. But since you only need the port, you can get it from this table. For https traffic you use the WC_defaulthost_secure.

Disclaimer: I have WAS 7 so I don't know if you see the same info on the same place that I do.

Comment: Hi Peter:

Thanks for the response.  I checked server_name > Ports but did not see that link, might be a WAS 6.x difference. I did have more luck by looking under Application servers > server_name > Transport Chain > WCInboundDefault, which appears correct since the port values listed align with what I was expecting.

I do appreciate your taking the time to respond.

Many thanks.